# Reference variables outside of function, in other classes

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I've written a program that essentially allows the user to make a profile, then later sign back in (after the code has been closed) and continue with their data saved to a text file.

```
class SignIn(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    self.configure(background="#FFC2B5")

    #Exit
    tk.Button(self, text="EXIT", command=EXIT, bg="#FFA795") .grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nesw", pady=10, padx=10)

    #InputDetails
    input_details = tk.Label(self, text="Please input your first and last name to access your profile")
    input_details.grid(column=0, row=1)

    #FIRSTNAME
    first_name_label = tk.Label(self, text="First Name:")
    first_name_label.grid(column=0, row=2)

    first_name_entry = tk.Entry(self)
    first_name_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)

    #LASTNAME
    last_name_label = tk.Label(self, text="Last Name:")
    last_name_label.grid(column=0, row=3)

    last_name_entry= tk.Entry(self)
    last_name_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

    def SignInConfirm():
        for file in os.listdir("/Users/140032/Desktop/SDD Major Project/"):
            filename = os.fsdecode(file)
            if filename.endswith(".txt"):
                completeName = os.path.join("/Users/140032/Desktop/SDD Major Project/", file)
                with open(completeName,'r') as inf:
                    dict_from_file = ast.literal_eval(inf.read())
                    if dict_from_file['First_Name'] == first_name_entry.get() and dict_from_file['Last_Name'] == last_name_entry.get():
                        print("Credentials Accepted. Welcome to 'The Mega Pop Quiz' " + dict_from_file["First_Name"] + "!")
                        global PermFile
                        PermFile = str(file)
                        print(PermFile)
                    else:
                        continue
                continue
            else:
                continue

        controller.show_frame("SubjectsPage")

    #CONFIRM
    confirm_button = tk.Button(self, text="SUBMIT", command=SignInConfirm )
    confirm_button.grid(column=2, row=4)
```

I'm having trouble with using the text file the user signs into in other parts of the code. Essentially, it iterates through every file, and when it finds a file that matches the input, it goes on with the program. PermFile is the file that the user signs into, and I can't find a way to reference the file later on outside of the function (in seperate classes). If I can get the name of the file the user logs into as a variable that can be used in other classes, I should be good to continue with the rest of the program.

Comment: Replace `global PermFile` with `self.perm_file`, and add `self.perm_file = None` in `__init__`... then, take some time out to read a little bit about classes and OOP in python.